# Converting the first and last name to pig latin

Tags: java, beginner, pig-latin

The following question was taken from *Absolute Java 5th ed.* by Walter Savitch:

> Write a program that starts with the string variable first set to your first name and the string variable last  set to your last name. Both names should be all lower- case. Your program should then create a new string that contains your full name in pig latin with the first letter capitalized for the first and last name. Use only the pig latin rule of moving the first letter to the end of the word and adding “ay.” Output the pig latin name to the screen. Use the substring  and  toUpperCase  methods to construct the new name.
>   For example, given
>   first = "walt";
>   last = "savitch";
>   the program should create a new string with the text “Altway Avitchsay” and print it.

This is the code that I have written:

```
    public class Question3 {

    private static String first;
    private static String last;
    private static String newName;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Question3 name = new Question3("walt", "savitch");

        System.out.println(name.convertName(first) + " "
                + name.convertName(last));

    }

    public Question3(String lowerCaseFirstName, String lowerCaseLastName) {
        first = lowerCaseFirstName;
        last = lowerCaseLastName;
    }

    private String convertName(String originalName) {
        String firstLetter = originalName.substring(0, 1);
        newName = nameWithoutFirstLetter(originalName) + firstLetter; // move first letter to the end
        newName = capitalizeFirstLetter() + nameWithoutFirstLetter(newName) // capitalize first letter and add "ay" to the end
                + "ay";
        return newName;
    }

    private String capitalizeFirstLetter() {
        String capitalFirstLetter = newName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
        return capitalFirstLetter;
    }

    private String nameWithoutFirstLetter(String name) {
        String restOfName = name.substring(1);
        return restOfName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Structure**

[Try not to use static variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil) `static` is for when the value of a field is the same across all instances of your object. But this isn't the case with peoples names.

What if you have two people? You would create your people:

```
    Question3 name = new Question3("walt", "savitch");
    Question3 anotherName = new Question3("john", "smith");
```

But then, you cannot use them the way you want.

If instead you would rewrite your code like this:

```
public class Question3 {

    private String first;
    private String last;
    private String newName;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Question3 name = new Question3("walt", "savitch");
        Question3 anotherName = new Question3("john", "smith");
        System.out.println(name.convertFullName());
        System.out.println(anotherName.convertFullName());

    }

    public Question3(String lowerCaseFirstName, String lowerCaseLastName) {
        first = lowerCaseFirstName;
        last = lowerCaseLastName;
    }

    public String convertFullName() {
        newName = convertName(first) + " " + convertName(last);
        return newName;
    }

    [...]
}
```

You can see that you can create however many people you want.

**Temporary variables**

If you don't need variables, you shouldn't create them. For example:

> ```
>     String restOfName = name.substring(1);
>     return restOfName;
> ```

could just be

```
    return name.substring(1);
```

**Functions**

You have a function which removes the first letter from a string, but you do not have one for getting the first letter of a string, but instead write that functionality directly in your `convertName` function. This seems inconsistent. I would either have a function for both or neither.

I also wouldn't operate on `newName` directly in `capitalizeFirstLetter`. None of your other functions (for example `nameWithoutFirstLetter`) do this, so it is inconsistent and can be confusing.

Also, right now, `newName` is just a temporary variable, which isn't ideal. You can never be sure what state it has. I would either change the code so it always holds the complete new name (for example `Altway Avitchsay`), or just get rid of `newName` completely.

Comment: I disagree to a certain extend with the temporary variables. *Sometimes* it is just better for readability to have four, well named temporary variables, instead of four chained method calls. In this case, yes, the variable can be scraped (especially as the function is only one line and well named).

Answer (score 6):

These variables don't need to be static: `first`, `last`. It would be better to define these inside the `main` method as local variables.

`newName` is a static variable, set in `convertName` and later used by `capitalizeFirstLetter`. This is not good design.

Also, setting static variables in the constructor is not a good practice: the variable will have the value set by the last instance created, which makes the variable unpredictable and prone to errors.

It would be better to rewrite this program without static variables, and without the constructor, for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String first = "walt";
    String last = "savitch";

    System.out.println(convertName(first) + " " + convertName(last));
}

private static String convertName(String name) {
    String firstLetter = getFirstLetter(name);
    String newName = nameWithoutFirstLetter(name) + firstLetter;
    return capitalizeFirstLetter(newName) + nameWithoutFirstLetter(newName) + "ay";
}

private static String getFirstLetter(String name) {
    return name.substring(0, 1);
}

private static String capitalizeFirstLetter(String name) {
    return getFirstLetter(name).toUpperCase();
}
```

I also added a `getFirstLetter` method, because you can reuse it in 2 places.